# Remove double quotes embracing variable strings from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have several files that contain this kind of line:

```
from="$variable_name" and other stuff
```

`$variable name` can change, so I could have

```
from="$myArray" and other stuff
from="$items" and other stuff
from="$list" and other stuff
```

I need to remove the double quotes that embrace the variable. The result should be

```
from=$myArray and other stuff
from=$items and other stuff
from=$list and other stuff
```

This replacement is needed in all files inside a folder.

Is it possible to achieve this with sed and/or awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for the examples you provided:

```
sed 's/"//g' <your_dir/*
```

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i` and remove the
`<`:

```
sed -i 's/"//g' your_dir/*
```

However, if there could be a `"` in the `and other stuff` part of the line
like:

```
from="$variable_name" and "other" stuff
```

then you could run 2 substitution commands, one to replace `"$` with `$` and
another to remove the second `"` like so (doing the replacement in-place):

```
sed -i 's/"\$/\$/; s/"//' your_dir/*
```

to get

```
from=$variable_name and "other" stuff
```

If you have other lines with double quotes but not of the form
`from="$variable_name"...` like this:

```
from="$myArray" and other stuff
from="$list" and "other" stuff
more "stuff"
```

then you can do:

```
sed -i 's/^from="\$/from=\$/; s/\(\$\w\+\)"/\1/' your_dir/*
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- `\$\w+` means '$OneOrMoreLetters'
- I remember this part by enclosing it in between `\(` and `\)`
- Then replace with and the remembered content `\1`
- since I didn't put the `"` inside the memory, it doesn't show up in the
  replacement.

Comment: what if I have to remove double quotes only from variables that follow the string from= ?

I have other variables embraced by double quotes in the file and I need this kind of replacement only for the first variable after from=

Comment: @splunk I updated the answer to add a command handling this case